# Post tracking in bulk REST API

Tags: api, shipment, shipment-tracking

We are currently create tracking one by one by using POST rest/V1/order/:orderId/ship:

```
{
 "notify": true, 
 "tracks": [ 
   { 
     "track_number": "1234567890",
     "title": "DPDPRE", 
     "carrier_code": "custom" 
   } 
 ]
```

}

it works fine,
But now we need to POST in Bulk, we have tried /bulk/V1/order/byOrderId/ship:

```
    [
    {
        "orderId": "284",
        "shipment": {
            "notify": true,
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "track_number": "1234567890",
                    "title": "CODE",
                    "carrier_code": "null"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "orderId": "285",
        "shipment": {
            "notify": true,
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "track_number": "0987654321",
                    "title": "CODE",
                    "carrier_code": "null"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

it ends with no error, but nothing is updated, the following job remains in progress
**Topic async.magento.sales.api.shiporderinterface.execute.post**
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to install rabbitMQ, see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/bulk-endpoints.html

Since you don't mention you have looked whether the queue was going well in your system, I imagine, you may need to setup this system?

Comment: Hello @herve-tribouilloy We already have RabbitQ running, we import catalog and prices